# Convert mp3 to static image waveform

Tags: java, android, mp3, wav

I am new to android studio and I'm doing my university project in it. Essentially what I am trying to do is allow the user to import an mp3 file from their device and then generate a static waveform image from the mp3 file.

I have searched around but all I can seem to find is animated visualizers that illustrate the waveform as the mp3 is playing on the device. I just want a static image that the user can save to their phone.Please see attached image.

waveform image

[image]

If anyone can assist me with this or direct me towards some resources that I could use it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For me your best option is to read your mp3 to a byte array representing each point of the sound wave ; you will find idea here : https://github.com/cemfi/meico/blob/master/src/meico/audio/Audio.java then you can analyse this data to get an image

Answer (score 0):

The best library you can use is FFMPEG, its an application you run by command line. 
Here some source code for the library: [source 1](https://github.com/hoary/JavaAV), [source 2](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper)

About the waveform image, ffmpeg have some resources to extract images from video/audio, you have to search for the command and see how to do it.

I never made something like that, so I don't know the exactly command but I know the better library you can use to make what you want to make, is ffmpeg.

If you have any other question about ffmpeg, feel free to ask me.